# Recyclerview adapter data don't change

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I'm using Recyclerview adapter to put images inside a Recyclerview
My code logic is to get the images URL from a JSON after parsing it, then the adapter should put the images inside a Recyclerview.
The images URL depend on certain SharedPreferences, but the problem is when the SharedPreferences change the images don't change with it, they only change when i restart the application

My Recyclerview Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public Context context;
public ArrayList<MoviesData> array;
public LayoutInflater inflater;


RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<MoviesData> array)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.array = array;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView image;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
         image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.oneMovieBlockImageView);
    }



}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_block,parent,false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rootview);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Picasso.with(context).load(array.get(position).getPoster_path()).into(holder.image);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return array.size();
}}
```

onPostExecute method

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MoviesData> result) {
        if (result != null) {

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),moviesDatas);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));



        }
    }
```

This is how the images URL should change depending on the SharedPreferences

```
 if(sortByStr.equals("popular"))
            {
                url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=9a005dd380ec772cf6045b8c370f8ef7");
            }

            else if(sortByStr.equals("top_rated"))
            {
                url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=9a005dd380ec772cf6045b8c370f8ef7");
            }

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
```

My MoviesData class where i collect all the data inside

```
public class MoviesData implements Parcelable{

MoviesData()
{


}

private String title,rate,release,overview,poster_path;

protected MoviesData(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    rate = in.readString();
    release = in.readString();
    overview = in.readString();
    poster_path = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<MoviesData> CREATOR = new Creator<MoviesData>() {
    @Override
    public MoviesData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MoviesData(in);
    }

    @Override
    public MoviesData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MoviesData[size];
    }
};

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setRate(String rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public void setRelease(String release) {
    this.release = release;
}

public void setOverview(String overview) {
    this.overview = overview;
}

public void setPoster_path(String poster_path) {
    this.poster_path = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + poster_path;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public String getRelease() {
    return release;
}

public String getOverview() {
    return overview;
}

public String getPoster_path() {
    return poster_path;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(rate);
    dest.writeString(release);
    dest.writeString(overview);
    dest.writeString(poster_path);
}}
```

And this function where i set all the data (including the images URL) inside the MoviesData class

```
 private ArrayList<MoviesData> getMoviesDataFromJson(String moviesJsonStr) throws JSONException
    {


        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(moviesJsonStr);
        JSONArray moviesArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray("results");


        for(int i = 0; i <moviesArray.length(); i++)
        {


           JSONObject movieObject = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);


            MoviesData movie = new MoviesData();

            movie.setPoster_path(movieObject.getString("poster_path"));
            movie.setTitle(movieObject.getString("title"));
            movie.setOverview(movieObject.getString("overview"));
            movie.setRate(movieObject.getString("vote_average"));
            movie.setRelease(movieObject.getString("release_date"));
            moviesDatas.add(movie);

        }


        return moviesDatas;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After call `getMoviesDataFromJson` method.

From the docs of `notifyDataSetChanged` :

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Hope it helps!

Comment: could you post the code where setting the url into MoviesData?

Comment: This is the line where i call the getMoviesDataFromJson method
`                return getMoviesDataFromJson(moviesJsonStr);
`
If i call 
`
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
`
After it, it says "Unreachable statement"

Comment: Put notifyDataSetChanged after call the method who returns getMoviesDataFromJson(moviesJsonStr), or do this in the method: ArrayList<MoviesData> movies = getMoviesDataFromJson(moviesJsonStr); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  return movies;

Answer (score 0):

Move this code

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

from `onPostExecute` to `onActivityCreated`. On `onPostExecute` check adapter is null or not. If it is `null` create it but is is not `null` refresh its data.

```
if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), moviesDatas);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        adapter.setData(moviesDatas);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

You need a method called `setData` in `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

```
public void setData(ArrayList<MoviesData> array) {
    this.array = array;
}
```

P.S.: Dont forget `commit` after editing `SharedPreferences`

Comment: I made these changes but still no luck, it's weird because it did work pretty well when i used GridView instead of Recyclerview, maybe the problem is inside my Recyclerview adapter ?

Comment: Btw, it says "No adapter attached; skipping layout" in the logcats

Comment: Can you try after change this "Picasso.with(context).load(array.get(position).getPoster_path()).into(holder.image);" in onBindViewHolder to "ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
        Picasso.with(context).load(array.get(position).getPoster_path()).into(viewHolder.image);"

Answer (score 0):

It worked after initializing `moviesDatas = new ArrayList<>();` inside `getMoviesDataFromJson` even without `notifyDataSetChanged`
To be honest i have no idea why it worked lol, does anybody have a clue ?